# Tag <a href> sem alterar a barra de localização

Tags: html, html5

Eu utilizo o bootstrap para criar aplicações para a web e acabei percebendo que em inúmeros exemplos, eles utilizam para botões o `<a href>` como neste [link](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/). queria saber como é que eu posso trabalhar da mesma forma sem que seja necessário que a localização da minha página seja alterada. Hoje sempre que preciso usar esta tag, tenho que fazer uma referência a um elemento nulo na tela como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<a href="#">teste</a>
```

Comment: você pode usar <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button">Primary</button>

Comment: alias n entendi, o que seria barra de localização ? botoes no bootstrap suportam várias tags, basta você usar o metodo type='button'

Comment: Estás a falar disto? http://i.stack.imgur.com/wMje2.png

Comment: Tenta esclarecer melhor o que pretendes.

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente você quer usar um link pra mudar certa parte da página ou alguma ação sem adicionar o `www.site.com/index.html#` né? Você pode fazer isso de várias formas, uma delas, embora não seja uma maneira muito "legal" utilizando o método `preventDefault()` do **JQuery**.

**Código HTML:**

```
<a href="#" id="meu-link">Meu link</a>
<div id="minha-div">Meu conteúdo.</div>
```

**Código JQuery:**

```
$('#meu-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Evita o evento padrão da ação seja executado, neste caso, evita que o link chame uma nova URL no browser

    // Ações
    // exemplo: $('#minha-div').html('Meu novo conteúdo.');
});
```

<sub>Documentação: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/</sub>

Comment: +1. `jQuery` é sempre uma solução agradável e elegante :)

Answer (score 1):

Há uma forma de deixa um link utilizando o javascript.

Exemplo:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Seu Link</a>
```

Dessa maneira, a sua página não vai "pular" quando você clicar nele.

Answer (score 1):

Há duas possibilidades para que a tag `a` não altere a url atual.

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">...</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">...</a>
```

Uma solução mais fácil de ser implementada que gosto de utilizar em meus scripts é a seguinte (exemplo utilizando jquery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[href='#']").attr("href", "javascript:void(0);");
});
```

Desta forma, você não precisa alterar os links manualmente e todos os links da página que possuem o atributo `href` igual a `#` serão automaticamente alterados para não influenciar na url. Mas vale lembrar que links adicionados na tela após a execução do script não serão afetados.